# How to extract data from Json format in html using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract data from a json format inside a html like the one below using beautifulsoup.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Movie",
  "url": "/title/tt1825683/",
  "name": "Black Panther",
  "image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg1MTY2MjYzNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTc4NTMwNDI@._V1_.jpg",
  "genre": [
    "Action",
    "Adventure",
    "Sci-Fi"
  ],
  "contentRating": "PG-13",
  "actor": [
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm1569276/",
      "name": "Chadwick Boseman"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm0430107/",
      "name": "Michael B. Jordan"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm2143282/",
      "name": "Lupita Nyong\u0027o"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm1775091/",
      "name": "Danai Gurira"
    }
  ],
  "director": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "url": "/name/nm3363032/",
    "name": "Ryan Coogler"
  },
  
}</script>
```

I got to this part where I extracted the whole json but how would I be able to specific attribute of the data?

```
soup_url = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
url_info = soup_url.find_all("script",type="application/ld+json")
```

Comment: Loop through the elements returned by `find_all`, get the text of each of them, then call `json.loads()`.

Comment: That will return a dictionary and then you can access it just like any other Python dictionary.

Comment: What part of that are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

As Barma mentioned use `json.loads()` but instead of `.text` use `.contents[0]` to get the dictionary part.

```
for script in soup_url.find_all("script",type="application/ld+json"):
        res_dict = json.loads(script.contents[0])
        print(res_dict['name'])
```

**Example**

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<script type="application/ld+json">{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Movie",
  "url": "/title/tt1825683/",
  "name": "Black Panther",
  "image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg1MTY2MjYzNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTc4NTMwNDI@._V1_.jpg",
  "genre": [
    "Action",
    "Adventure",
    "Sci-Fi"
  ],
  "contentRating": "PG-13",
  "actor": [
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm1569276/",
      "name": "Chadwick Boseman"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm0430107/",
      "name": "Michael B. Jordan"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm2143282/",
      "name": "Lupita Nyong\u0027o"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm1775091/",
      "name": "Danai Gurira"
    }
  ],
  "director": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "url": "/name/nm3363032/",
    "name": "Ryan Coogler"
  }
  
}</script>'''

soup_url = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for script in soup_url.find_all("script",type="application/ld+json"):
    res_dict = json.loads(script.contents[0])
    print(res_dict['name'])
```